# Pandas pd not populating with .append

Tags: python, pandas

I've successfully gathered data into a dictionary called 'data' with Sleenium & Python. the output of that dict looks like this:

```
data = {'Price': '£1,995', 'Title': 'BMW X3', 'Key Specs': ['2006 (56 reg)', 'SUV', '110,000 miles', '2.0L', '150BHP', 'Manual', 'Diesel'], 'Year': '2006 (56 reg)', 'Type': 'SUV', 'Milage': '110,000 miles', 'Displacement': '2.0L', 'Power': '150BHP', 'Transmission': 'Manual', 'Fuel': 'Diesel'}
```

I've created a Pandas DataFrame called 'df' at the start of the script, see below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Title', 'Price', 'Year', 'Type', 'Milage', 'Displacement', 'Power', 'Transmission', 'Fuel', 'Owner Count', 'Key Specs', 'Attention Grabber', 'URL'])
```

Sadly for some reason I'm not successful in appending the `data` to my `df`. via the following line (within a loop):

```
df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
```

Can you pls help?

The error message is as follows:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Title, Price, Year, Type, Milage, Displacement, Power, Transmission, Fuel, Owner Count, Key Specs, Attention Grabber, URL]
Index: []
```

Comment: FWIW your code produced a DataFrame with a single row for me in Pandas 1.2.4.

Comment: Thanks @HenryEcker, I upgraded Pandas but still no luck. Could you take a look? pastebin.com/8ZhuEwdu

Comment: Can you update your question to a single contiguous block of code that you're running including the print statement?

Comment: I can only guess one of the try excepts is causing the loop to break before you call the pd.DataFrame(data...) which is at the very bottom.

Comment: Thanks @HenryEcker, I'll look into that. I cannot update my question as you describe otherwise I'll get scolded by the mods. (happened before and they're right)

Comment: Hey! you founded solution or are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: @Csongor what is your expected result ? Could you add it in your question, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I removed the defined columns from the DataFrame and only left those that were being called. That did the trick, now my original code works. thanks for all the helpful feedback

Answer (score 1):

I can't say exactly why empty DataFrame with columns fails to append a line. But if you append the same line to the regular empty DataFrame, it works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
```

You can always add columns that the data are missing later.

Anyways, I strongly recommend against appending data line by line for performance reasons. For each such call `pandas` creates a new copy of the DataFrame. It would be more efficiently if you create a list with all the data you want to append, and then call `append` once.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of your code. This breaks your for-loop

```
try: 
            data['URL'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.js-click-handler listing-fpa-link tracking-standard-link')[0].get_attribute('href')
except:
            break
```

So, this doesn't get executed, and you end-up with an empty dataframe.

```
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Title', 'Price', 'Year', 'Type', 'Milage', 'Displacement', 'Power', 'Transmission', 'Fuel', 'Owner Count', 'Key Specs', 'Attention Grabber', 'URL'])
```

Also, since your dict contains a list element inside, you need to do it like this, or you will get a new record for every element in 'Key Specs' list.

```
        df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=['Title', 'Price', 'Year', 'Type', 'Milage', 'Displacement', 'Power', 'Transmission', 'Fuel', 'Owner Count', 'Key Specs', 'Attention Grabber', 'URL'])
```

Comment: Thank you @MySlav but I'm afraid I commented out that block of code and still didnt work. :(

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this would be

```py
num = len(df) + 1

df.loc[num] = data
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned, that you are placing `df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)` **within a loop**

Try like below without any loop.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Price': '£1,995', 'Title': 'BMW X3', 'Key Specs': ['2006 (56 reg)', 'SUV', '110,000 miles', '2.0L', '150BHP', 'Manual', 'Diesel'], 'Year': '2006 (56 reg)', 'Type': 'SUV', 'Milage': '110,000 miles', 'Displacement': '2.0L', 'Power': '150BHP', 'Transmission': 'Manual', 'Fuel': 'Diesel'}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Title', 'Price', 'Year', 'Type', 'Milage', 'Displacement', 'Power', 'Transmission', 'Fuel', 'Owner Count', 'Key Specs', 'Attention Grabber', 'URL'])
df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Considering list of data as input, below snippet would be helpful.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Title', 'Price', 'Year', 'Type', 'Milage', 'Displacement', 'Power', 'Transmission', 'Fuel', 'Owner Count', 'Key Specs', 'Attention Grabber', 'URL'])

# make your input as list
data = [{'Price': '£1,995', 
        'Title': 'BMW X3', 
        'Key Specs': ['2006 (56 reg)', 'SUV', '110,000 miles', '2.0L', '150BHP', 'Manual', 'Diesel'], 
        'Year': '2006 (56 reg)', 
        'Type': 'SUV', 
        'Milage': '110,000 miles', 
        'Displacement': '2.0L', 
        'Power': '150BHP', 
        'Transmission': 'Manual', 
        'Fuel': 'Diesel'},
        
        {'Price': '£2,995', 
        'Title': 'BMW X7', 
        'Key Specs': ['2016 (66 reg)', 'SUV', '210,000 miles', '4.0L', '250BHP', 'Automatic', 'Diesel'], 
        'Year': '2016 (66 reg)', 
        'Type': 'SUV', 
        'Milage': '210,000 miles', 
        'Displacement': '4.0L', 
        'Power': '250BHP', 
        'Transmission': 'Manual', 
        'Fuel': 'Diesel'}]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I need this to be inside the loop, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi @Csongor I have added some more snippets, along with my answer, If anything more is needed try re-explaining your issue/needs.